# Drag and Drop Custom Control Isn't working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have built a custom `ListView` to allow me to drag and drop. with some help from other questions and blog post i have gotten this far.

I am using `MVVM` in the implementation of the `UserControl` but while building the actual Custom `ListView` i am just using the code behind. as i thought this would be easier.

How can I implement code below to get to add to ViewModel ICollection?

**update:**

please note that I think that the reason this is happening is because I am trying to add an `object` to `ObservableCollection<person>()`;

exception:

> Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

XAML: Implementation:

```
<controls:DragNDropListView 
            x:Name="ListView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}"
            DragDropEffects="Copy"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name"></controls:DragNDropListView>

<controls:DragNDropListView 
            x:Name="ListView1"
            Grid.Column="1" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Persons1}" 
            DisplayMemberPath="Name"
            DragDropEffects="Copy"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel 
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        Persons1 = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        Persons.Clear();
        Persons1.Clear();
        foreach (var person in Data.People().ToList())
        {
            Persons.Add(person);
            Persons1.Add(person);
        }

    }
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons1 { get; set; }
}
```

Drag code:

```
private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
        Vector diff = _startPoint - mousePos;
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
            (Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
             Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance))
        {
            if (ListView != null)
            {
                ListViewItem listViewItem =
                    FindAnchestor<ListViewItem>((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource);
                if (listViewItem != null)
                {
                    var item = ListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(listViewItem);  //NOTE:this is an object not a Person like observeablecollection in ViewModel.
                    DataObject dragData = new DataObject("myFormat", item);
                    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listViewItem, dragData, DragDropEffects); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Drop code that is throwing exception:

```
private void OnDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("myFormat"))
        {
            var item = e.Data.GetData("myFormat");
            if (item != null)
            {
                Items.Add(item);//this is where it throws exception
            }
        }
    }
```